# How to print all the matched string using awk?

Tags: shell-script, awk, regular-expression

My inputs are something like:

```
["https://www.tesing.com/watch/80239279"],
["https://www.testing.com/watch/80240715?source=35"],
["https://www.testing.com/watch/80242619?trackId=254015180&tctx=0%2C0%2Ce336905e-6b5c-4a93-ad18-57ae35b6eb08-583558810%2C29fea9da-2bf8-43b0-b26a-2da637154825_96118138X20XX1560732016031%2C29fea9da-2bf8-43b0-b26a-2da637154825_ROOT"],
["https://www.testing.com/watch/80242619?tctx=1%252C0%252C%252C%252C"],
```

so I want extract only *parameters* (eg: trackId,SourceId)

my *regex* is `/[\?\\&]{1,2}\w+=/`.

### file.awk

```
BEGIN {}
{
    match($0, /[\?\\&]{1,2}\w+=/){print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}
}
END {}
```

But it is printing only one matched string.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the question is just `awk` related, note, that it's much easier to achieve the same with pure `grep` (especially grep) or `sed`:

```
grep -o '\?[^=]*='
```

or

```
sed -n 's/.*\(\?[^=]*=\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested with below command and it worked fine

```
awk -F "=" '{print $1}' filename |awk -F "?" '{print "?"$2}'| sed '/^\?$/d'
```

output

```
?source=
?trackId=
?tctx=
```